# ImportError: libkfusion.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: python, kinect, python-import, importerror, library-path

I have been trying to reproduce a framework from a paper where it uses Kinect Fusion library.

When I am running a test script, I got the errors:

```
(darnn) weizhang@long:~/DA-RNN$ sudo ./experiments/scripts/test_kinect_fusion.sh 0
+ set -e
+ export PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True
+ PYTHONUNBUFFERED=True
+ export CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
+ CUDA_VISIBLE_DEVICES=0
++ date +%Y-%m-%d_%H-%M-%S
+ LOG=experiments/logs/test_kinect_fusion.txt.2018-06-17_12-44-13
+ exec
++ tee -a experiments/logs/test_kinect_fusion.txt.2018-06-17_12-44-13
+ echo Logging output to experiments/logs/test_kinect_fusion.txt.2018-06-17_12-44-13
Logging output to experiments/logs/test_kinect_fusion.txt.2018-06-17_12-44-13
+ ./tools/test_kinect_fusion.py --gpu 0 --imdb rgbd_scene_trainval --cfg experiments/cfgs/rgbd_scene.yml --rig data/RGBDScene/camera.json
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./tools/test_kinect_fusion.py", line 15, in <module>
    from kinect_fusion import kfusion
ImportError: libkfusion.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It simply says that it cannot find a shared object, which does exist. It is included as well, which can be checked by `echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH` as :

`/home/weizhang/Pangolin/build/src:/usr/local/cuda-8.0/lib64::/usr/local/cuda/lib64:/usr/local/cuda/extras/CUPTI/lib64:/home/weizhang/DA-RNN/lib/kinect_fusion/build`

This might be a too specified question but I am curious why this happened and what might be able to solve it.

Appreciate any comments!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Any environment variables set in your local environment are lost when you run `sudo`.  For example, if my local environment includes:

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/some/path
```

Then running `env` as myself, I see:

```
$ env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/some/path
$
```

But using `sudo` the variable is not visible, because `sudo` creates a new, sanitized environment:

```
$ sudo env | grep LD_LIBRARY_PATH
$
```

The best solution for you is probably to set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` inside your `./experiments/scripts/test_kinect_fusion.sh` script.

Comment: Thank you so much! This really explains the confusion.